# Autocomplete in JQUERY MOBILE text input

Tags: jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I searched a lot on net but couldnt find any solution. I am making a webapp in which I want 2 textbox to get data input from user. I want autocomplete feature in this textbox. The list of tags for autocomplete is available locally. I tried listview but what I want is that after user select some option from autocomplete hints, the textbox should have the selected value, and through some object, i should get the value of textbox to be used by javascript/php. This is a very basic thing, but I'm not able to do. Please help me out

I tried this jsfiddle.net/ULXbb/48/ . But the problem in this is that both listview gets same value after I select something in 1 listview.

Comment: Both text both are in the same page? Or separate pages?

Comment: What is the input text?  Addresses or something else?

Comment: Replace this `$('input[data-type="search"]').val($(this).text());` with this `$.mobile.activePage.find('input[data-type="search"]').val($(this).text());`. This will add values to search input in active page only.

Comment: Check modifications here http://jsfiddle.net/ULXbb/236/

Comment: @Jeffrey ..Input text is basically 2 words..

Comment: @Omar..both text are in same page..check this http://jsfiddle.net/ULXbb/237/ ..this is what i want..it still has the same problem..when i enter something in 1st filter, it automatically gets copied to 2nd filter

Comment: Then easily give each one a unique ID or class.

Comment: i did not understand..can you elaborate? also, suppose in my php file,  i want to access the text in the filter, hw can i access that?

Comment: I got what you mean http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ULXbb/240/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order not to add the same value to both search input, you need to target them using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/). jQuery-Mobile, enhances list-view with data filter in a different way.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dLeUw/)**

```html
<form>
  <input>
</form>
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>
    <a>text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `form` where the `input` is located, is on the same level of the `ul`. To target the `input` box, you need to use `.prev('form').find('input')`. Check the demo and the new code below.

```js
$("input[data-type='search']").keyup(function () {
   if ($(this).val() === '') {
       $(this).closest('form').next("[data-role=listview]").children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
   }
});

$('a.ui-input-clear').click(function () {
   $(this).closest('input').val('');
   $(this).closest('input').trigger('keyup');
});

$("li").click(function () {
   var text = $(this).find('.ui-link-inherit').text();
   $(this).closest('[data-role=listview]').prev('form').find('input').val(text);
   $(this).closest('[data-role=listview]').children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot. However, i still have 1 doubt. I want to access text value of both filters in some other javascript script. How can i do that? What shall i pass in document.getElementById?

Comment: @user1518793 it depends when you want to read the values. check the updated demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ULXbb/244/
check this..on clicking 'Submit' button, i want to run a javascript function and want to access those 2 filter values in that function..

Comment: sorry..i am still not able to understand how can i access those 2 filter values??

Comment: @user1518793 check the last part in the code in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dLeUw/

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping man..wasted a day ofine on his..really thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @user714852 I have extended your answer just add this line in the script tag:

`$("#mylist li" ).addClass('ui-screen-hidden');`

It will do wonders.

A working example: [Listview Autocomplete - Enhanced](http://jsbin.com/UGARopu/2)