# JQueryMobile autocomplete click on entry dont change input value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I try to make a autocomplete input with jquery mobile. '

So I found a demo for this here:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/

But my problem is, that I cant change the value of the input field by clicking on a listed entry.

I want that if I click on a listed entry the value of the input field gets the value of the entry like the normal autocomplete behavior.

Here is a SSCCE (I couldnt bring the page to work on jsfiddle so I used pastebin):

http://pastebin.com/QmtEQegF

Thanks for any help

Comment: Well I found this thread which helped me a little to understand how I have to do this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980018/autocomplete-in-jquery-mobile-text-input

But the problem is, that this runs on Jquery-1.6.4 and I use jquery 1.10.2 and there are several changes on it. 

So I modified the jquery part by searching for the right css class but still have no effect. 

Here is the SSCCE:

http://pastebin.com/6StF9TKG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more or less the same as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980018/autocomplete-in-jquery-mobile-text-input).

In your code, you're using `.ready()` and not attaching `click` event to dynamically generated `li`. `.ready()` isn't recommended to be used in jQM, instead, use [jQuery Mobile 1.4 events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/).

The equivalent event to `.ready()` is `pagecreate` as it replaces `pageinit` in jQM 1.3.2 and below.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#startseite", function () {

  /* retrieve text from clicked li */
  $(document).on("click", "li", function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).closest("ul").prev("form").find("input").val(text);
  });

  $("#autocomplete").on("filterablebeforefilter", function (e, data) {
    /* rest of code */
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Q8dBH/)**