# jquery mobile 1.3.2. listview autocomplete show selected item

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, selection

I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821583/jquerymobile-autocomplete-click-on-entry-dont-change-input-value) for displaying value of selected listview li element, but it doesn't work for me.

I am creating the listview dynamically like this  -

```
    $.post ("/Search", { "type":"tz" }, function(data) {
    var d = data.timezones;
    var catList = "<ul id='tzlist' data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-filter-reveal='true' data-filter-placeholder='search timezone...' data-inset='true'>";
    $.each (d, function(i, item) 
    {
        catList += "<li><a href='' onclick='seltz(this);'>";
        catList += item.tzone;
        catList += "</a></li>";

    });
    catList += "</ul>";
    $(sName).empty();
    $(sName).append(catList);
    $(sName).trigger("create");
}, "json");
```

The onclick function is -

```
function seltz(el) {
var txt=$(el).text();
alert(txt);
$(this).closest("ul").prev("form").find("input").val(txt);
}
```

The alert shows correct value of the clicked li item but the input does not reflect that value.
Any ideas why this may not be working?

Thanks in advance.

RD

Answer (score 0):

OK. So I searched through other posts and realized what changes were needed. 
First, I changed my function and removed the onclick call -

```
    $.post ("/whnwh/Search", { "type":"tz" }, function(data) 
    {
      var d = data.timezones;
      var catList = "<ul id='tzlist' data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-filter-reveal='true' data-filter-placeholder='search timezone...' data-inset='true'>";
      $.each (d, function(i, item) 
      {
        catList += "<li>";
        catList += item.tzone;
        catList += "</li>";
      });
      catList += "</ul>";
      $(sName).empty();
      $(sName).append(catList);
      $(sName).trigger("create");
    }, "json");
```

then, in html file, I added this callback -

```
    $("#timezone").on("click", "li",  function () {
        window.seltz = $(this).text();
        $(this).closest("ul").prev("form").find("input").val(window.seltz);
        $("#timezone li" ).addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
    });
```

This resolved the issue of displaying the selected li item in search input widget.

jquery developers - this is a simple but often required task and should be added to the listview api.

I do have another question. The above code allows an user to select a timezone from a listview. If I know the user's timezone, how can I pre-populate the input widget? I tried the same callback as above but it does not work. Any thoughts?

Thanks

RD